# Sequelize returning more fields than requested

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this function,

```
module.exports.getDepartments = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        sequelize.sync().then(function () {
            Departments.findAll({
                attributes: ['departmentId', 'departmentName']
            }).then(function(data){
                    resolve(data);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                reject("Error: " + err);
            })
        });
    }
)};
```

And when I `console.log()` the data, I get all records with all these weird fields!

```
Departments {
  dataValues: { departmentId: 5, departmentName: '' },
  _previousDataValues: { departmentId: 5, departmentName: '' },
  _changed: {},
  _modelOptions:
   { timestamps: true,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
  _options:
   { isNewRecord: false,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
     raw: true,
     attributes: [ 'departmentId', 'departmentName' ] },
  __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
  isNewRecord: false }

  Departments {
  dataValues: { departmentId: 6, departmentName: 'TEST' },
  _previousDataValues: { departmentId: 6, departmentName: 'TEST' },
  _changed: {},
  _modelOptions:
   { timestamps: true,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
  _options:
   { isNewRecord: false,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
     raw: true,
     attributes: [ 'departmentId', 'departmentName' ] },
  __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
  isNewRecord: false }
```

I've had to shorten it by like 20 fields, but you get the idea. What's going on? This is preventing me from running `res.render` back on my `server.js` because it's expecting on `departmentId` and `departmentName`, but is getting way more.

Comment: If you are using node.js and express you can use `res.jsonp(response);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct Sequelize to return raw data. By default it creates instances on the row results.

Example:

```
Project.findAll({ where: { ... }, raw: true })
```